# Creating an Object from Optional<Object>

Tags: java, java-stream, option-type

So I've created a stream which comes from a List but I'm having some trouble converting it into a `<ObjectType>,` here's what I've tried:

```
ObjectType sco = getList().stream()
                          .filter(p -> p.getValue() == value)
                          .findFirst(); //also tried .orElse(null);
```

would anyone, please, be so kind as to suggest where I'm going wrong?
(I apologize if this has been asked before but I couldn't find a discussion on this particular topic (or didn't know the proper terms to search for))

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happened when you tried `.orElse(null)`?

Comment: well I tried it without findFirst() and that was my downfall...
If you use .findFirst().orElse(null) like @Brian Angew suggests it works perfectly.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`findFirst()` gives you an `Optional` and you then have to decide what to do if it's not present. So `findFirst().orElse(null)` should give you the object *or null if it's not present*

You *could* just do a `.get()` on the `Optional`, but that could be regarded as poor practice since `get()` will throw an exception if `Optional` has no content. You should normally assert presence/absence of the `Optional` and decide what to do in each case (that's why it's there - so that you know something is truly *optional* and you have to determine what to do)

If you have an action you want to perform on object presence, and you don't want to do anything on *absence*, you can call `.ifPresent()` and provide a lambda as an argument. That will be called with the contained object, if present.

As of Java 9, a further solution would be to use [Optional.ifPresentOrElse()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/optional-ifpresentorelse-method-in-java-with-examples/)

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be looking for `findFirst().or Else(null)`.  `findFirst()` will return an `Optional` - empty in the case of an empty steam.

Unless I misunderstood your comment. Have you tried this, or did you try `orElse(null)` without `findFirst()`?